# What do you call a website which is not in beta, but a re-launch with possible teething problems?

Tags: copywriting, feedback, wording, messages, beta

We are launching a new website soon. We have ran some beta versions to users, but we are going to finally press the button, turn off the old one and only have the new website.

I want to let users know through some banners and messages on the site, that basically the site has been completely overhauled and that there might still be some issues due to the sheer size and amount of content and different layouts we have.

I guess since the old site has gone and this is it, I cannot then use the word beta?

Is there a better word to use for these banners, messages?

Comment: it's called "version 1.0" as most users expect the first release to be buggy.

Comment: **Slashdot** would be appropriate. As in, _"This website is a bit of a slashdot"_

Comment: Honestly... Most companies just use the word "Beta" to signify their platform is running a new website. You can still invite user feedback, even if you follow convention.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**The fewer words the better, and no words at all are better than negative words.**

Don't say *why* you think there might be a problem, or even that you think there is likely *to be* a problem. Instead just make it easy for them to contact you in the event that they do *happen* to come across a problem.

I quite liked an experience I had recently at [surfdome](https://www.surfdome.com/) where it was clear there was a new site, and that I could leave feedback if I wanted, but not in a way that made me doubt the integrity of the site right from the start. The feedback link uses [UserSnap](https://usersnap.com/) to report bugs and comments.

[image]

Comment: The text "Welcome to our new site. Leave feedback" is just brilliant! (The graphics design of the part too, actually.)

Comment: I agree that this is great copy and a great solution. I would also recommend that your 404 and error pages are ready for the launch, so that any problems during the launch will be handled gracefully by your site.

Comment: And if you're not actively tracking 404/error pages (I've seen phrases along the lines of "_Oops something went wrong. If this happened from within the site a report has been sent to the administrator_") then it might make sense to have the "Leave Feedback" link on those pages so people can let you know how it happened).

Comment: Maybe you could support "Use old design" because when something bugs or the user doesnt like the page you can give him an option of going back to the way he usually uses the website